# How to drive the test cases using an Excel file in Watir?

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, watir, browser-automation

Is it possible to drive the test cases using an Excel file in watir?

Here I mean to say we currently are writing the Test cases in test class, but I am thinking if I can drive the testcase from an Excel file like below

```
TestCase    | Run
------------+------
test_Login  | Yes
```

`RUN` column should decide whether this test case should run or not.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It is likely possible However, it really depends on your test framework - some may take more or less work.

Comment: I've run it from FitNesse tables. But I wouldn't do it again. I think it's easier to debug from rspec or cucumber.